# Cramer's rule and understanding Area/Volume

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

I'm having trouble connecting all the ideas we're learning in Linear Algebra. On the one hand, I understand how to find determinants, and therefore expansion factors. I also am fairly certain I have a grasp on Cramer's Rule to solve for variables in a system.

However, going through problems in the book, I come across a set of questions that asks me to find areas and volumes using Cramer's rule. Something like this:

---

Interpret the determinant as an area or volume and as an expansion factor. Use Cramer's Rule.

Find the area of the parallelogram defined by $ \ \left( \begin{array}{cc}
3 \\
7 \end{array} \right) $ and $ \ \left( \begin{array}{cc}
8 \\
2 \end{array} \right) $

---

I was understand the impression that Cramer's rule was only for solving linear systems using determinants. It would be very easy to just answer this with $ \ \left|Det\left( \begin{array}{cc}
3 & 8\\
7 & 2\end{array} \right)\right| $, but that doesn't feel like I'm using Cramer's rule at all.

I think an answer to this simple question will help me understand how to answer more abstract questions like "Why is the volume of a tetrahedron in R3 defined by v1, v2, and v3 one sixth of the volume of the parallelepiped defined by v1, v2, and v3?". Any guidance would be appreciated.